# My folder is disappearing, how can I find out where it is going?

Tags: centos, files

I have a CentOS 5 server that is file hosting by samba on a small network of 25 or so desktop server 2003 environment. Every night, a folder on one of the samba shares of this server is mysteriously disappearing. Every day we restore from a backup, but every night it disappears. The samba config is thus:

```
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

The permissions for the folder itself is wide open. I think there might be a scheduled task on one of the desktops that is deleting it, but I don't know how to be sure. Is there a way to determine what is happening to the folder every night?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the verbosity of samba server or use an `inotify` script to monitor the folder and run a `netstat -tnp` to find the workstation connected at the server at that moment.